# Android NetworkImageView disappear in RecyclerView after Scrolling list (Volley)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-volley, networkimageview

Am using `NetworkImageView` with volley library and `RecyclerView`. After scrolling list some images disappear from the `NetworkImageView`. I am writing my code in the `onBindViewHolder()` method inside the Adapter class. And code is given below:

```
pvh1.imgmovie.setDefaultImageResId(R.drawable.banner);
pvh1.imgmovie.setImageUrl("image_url", imageLoader);`
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem. No luck finding the answer so far. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40916054/recyclerview-networkimageview-volley-doesnt-show-up

Comment: As there is no response, I did a work around by avoiding NetworkImageView altogether. See my sample code in the link above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know `NetworkImageView` but I advise you to use Picasso to download images from the web, it's great! Use it with a normal `ImageView`!

```
Picasso.with(context).load(image_url).into(image_view);
```

https://github.com/square/picasso